# T-SQL Script to copy data from one server to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to copy data from one server to another using a `T-SQL` script? We have a code promotion process that makes using the import wizard less than optimal for our team so I am looking into a script I can simply have someone run in Management Studio that will do the trick.

Comment: Linked server or SSIS package would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 
First create a `Linked Server` to other server, then you can access the target server by 4 part Names, for example:

```
Insert into Server2.Database2.dbo.MapTable1 select * from table1
```

p.s you can add linked server by [sp_addLinkedServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)